# identify user who stopped the azure vm

Tags: azure

one of our critical vm got stopped and we tried to get the logs to find out the user who did it but we are unable to get from application insights.

we don't have a separate monitoring tool set for the VMs. Is it possible to find the details who did it?

thanks,
Usha

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just click on the Activity Log from the VM blade:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. we checked the same but its not showing any user details. The health event updates logs showing that the vm is stopping. No other logs or user details related to stopping the VM.

Comment: Did you adjust the timespan?

Comment: yes I did. It doesn't show anything. I got the below details info from the log.                        "submissionTimestamp": "2019-08-19T07:08:41.7796005Z",
    "subscriptionId": "**************************************",
    "properties": {
        "title": "This virtual machine is stopping and deallocating as requested by an authorized user or process",
        "details": "VirtualMachineDeallocationInitiated",
        "currentHealthStatus": null,
        "previousHealthStatus": null,
        "type": "Downtime",
        "cause": "UserInitiated"

Comment: Do you have auto-shutdown enabled on the VM?! https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Educator-Developer-Blog/Azure-Virtual-Machine-auto-shutdown/ba-p/379342

Comment: No, nothing enabled. The VM is running from past 7 months. This is the first time the vm went to stopped state. The only update in the logs is as mentioned above and it was from health event.

Comment: hm then I would open a ticket with the Azure support

Comment: It might be maintenance by Azure which required a reboot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/understand-vm-reboot#planned-maintenance